# Unable to add custom apps to new custom policy in Teams admin

Tags: microsoft-teams

Unable to add apps to custom policy in Teams admin.

After adding the new app in the new customs policy. On the Click of save button, there is an error displaying "We can’t save the app setup policy right now. Please try again. If you continue to have problems, contact Microsoft Customer Support."

Would someone face the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got solved automatically after two days. No configurational changes or custom scripts has been executed in order to resolve this query.

Comment: Microsoft Product Team should explain this miracle :)

Comment: We have the same issue. I hate these unspecific errors, no idea what the problem is.